# Get BackTrace from Core file without GDB

Tags: gdb, coredump

Is there a way to get the back trace from a core file without using GDB?

There is a crash of the program and a core file is generated but there is not GDB installed at the target machine. Is there any way to get to know the backtrace from the core file without GDB?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the back trace from a core file without using GDB?

There certainly is. There are other debuggers, and the application may produce a stack trace itself without even generation `core` file in the first place. [Google logging library](https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/) includes code for doing this on Linux.

However, in your case it may be easier to simply analyze the `core` with GDB.

> there is not GDB installed at the target machine.

You can analyze the `core` on any other machine (usually called host -- the machine on which you are compiling the binary).

For this you need:

- system libraries from the target machine (if your binary is dynamically linked) and
- appropriately configured cross-GDB (often included in embedded development kits).

Answer (score 1):

Getting a backtrace from a core file is very much architecture and OS specific, if you plan to extract it all by yourself.
gdb is a portable program which works on multiple architectures. Anyway gdb uses two techniques to extract the backtrace from coredump:
1. Following the link list of frame pointer (ebp in case of x86 architecture).
2. Using the exception handling framework to do virtual unwinding.
gdb requires binaries to extract the backtrace from coredump since binaries contains information, how to start the virtual unwinding.

After this point my answer is specific to linux-x86_64 architecture.

Using the frame pointer i.e. rbp does not work when it comes to extracting backtrace reliably if frame pointer is omitted or it is optimized program. On x86_64 architecture, compilers e.g. gcc emit .eh_frame section which is used by gdb to do virtual unwinding(remember I am not talking about source level debugging of gdb). But gdb requires binaries to do virtual unwinding since gdb assumes core is without executable contents since on linux box kernel by default 
dumps only data segments.

If you have complete coredump and no binaries on linux-x86_64 then following project might help you.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/core-dump-analyzer/